# Is my shopping list database schema good enough?

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema, database-diagrams

I'm wondering if my schema is correct? It's intended to hold shopping list items for each `user`, a user belongs to a `household`. `Items` will be added to the `household`.

The stocklist will to hold the quantity of an `iID (item ID)` and that `iID` is belongs to a `hhID` .

So at the moment

- stocklist.hhID references household.hhID
- household.adminID references users.uID
- items.hhID references household.hhID
- stocklist.iID references items.iID

I'm wondering if these relationships are viable? Even more importantly what do you think of the schema?

[image: Database EER diagram]

Posted from my unused account before.

Comment: From your illustration it seems that `users.hhID` also references `household.hhID`. Is that so or is the picture just not up-to-date?

Comment: Yeah thats correct @AndriyM - Should I be removing some foreign keys?

Comment: I would kill the relationship between `Stocklist` and `Users` and add a new tables `Orders` and `OrderItems`. Relate `Household` with `Orders` and `Orders` with `OrderItems`

Comment: Hm,is this tool using lines instead of fields? In that case it seems User.hhid is not needed as it is given by the reference. If not, I am not sure which field is which reference?

Comment: It is not clear what relationships you want to implement. What is a shopping list? Is it the same as the stocklist? Can a user have many shopping/stock lists? Can a shopping/stock list have many items?

Comment: @NelsonCasanova there desn't seem to be a relationship between stocklist and users. It's between stocklist and household ("stocklist.hhID references household.hhID") but the line in the drawing passes behind the users image.

Comment: I would strongly recommend naming the relationships with domain-specific terms. There are a lot of lines between user and household. What do each of them mean?

Answer (score 1):

Your schema has a circular reference and redundant columns/foreign keys.

Consider the following normalization of your data structure:

- Put itens as a reference table, no Foreign Keys.
- Stocklist references Items
- Users have a FK to Household, no use on including the reverse relation because you can always find the User records for a given Household with a table Inner Join.

Comment: You also said to put a switch the reference on the items>stocklist table?

Comment: Yes for the first and no for the second. Consider removing Household references items. The stocklist referencing items is the relation you already have on your diagram.